# Why have a fake LR-WPAN driver?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers

In the Linux kernel configuration, a fake LR-WPAN driver can be enabled and added to the kernel that will be compiled. Why would someone want a fake LR-WPAN driver? I assume it would be for debugging, but I do not want to only assume. The documentation and Google do not appear to have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [description in the kernel configuration file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ieee802154/Kconfig) (`Kconfig` in the driver directory):

```
tristate "Fake LR-WPAN driver with several interconnected devices"
depends on  IEEE802154_DRIVERS
---help---
Say Y here to enable the fake driver that serves as an example
of HardMAC device driver.
```

This driver allows testing, debugging and experimenting with Linux's IEEE 802.15.4 subsystem, even if you have no corresponding hardware. Its source can also be a template to write a driver for some IEEE 802.15.4 driver. It is only of interest to programmers of IEEE 802.15.4-related tools and drivers.